# header slide up effect works but not the words with the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a slide up effect for the header. At first place header would be at the bottom of he page, after I click the trigger, The header with the fullscreen image animates upwards and reveals a grid of image anchors with a title, the slide up effect works but the header still stay at the same place which messes up with the image grid, actually they works, so I wonder why the words with the header is not moving upwards. Here is the jsfiddle for output display: http://jsfiddle.net/4mmu87py/
  Noted that the effect adopts some techniques like Flexbox and CSS Transitions.

The cods that determines the position of header is showned below:

```
.intro__content {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;


width: 480px;
font-size: 1.15em;
padding: 0;
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure your question is all that clear... what do you mean the header does not move upwards? It seems to do so in your fiddle.

Comment: @Bolboa Since header should have the slide effect to slide up when I click the trigger, but the fonts didn't slide up just remain the same place, though the image grid still reveals, it works in Google chrome but not in emulator